# In Nielsen and Chuang, how can $\frac{1}{2(e-1)}$ result from $\frac12\int_{e-1}^{2^{t-1}-1}dl\frac{1}{l^2}$?

Tags: mathematics, textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, quantum-phase-estimation

From Nielsen and Chuang's book: $\textit{Quantum computation and quantum information}$, how can (5.34) equal (5.33)?  I.e.

$$\dfrac{1}{2} \int_{e-1}^{2^{t-1}-1} dl \dfrac{1}{l^2} = \dfrac{1}{2(e-1)}.$$

Comment: Probably a typo, it should read leq again (note that t>1).

Comment: As @M.Stern commented, this is probably a typo as 

$$ \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{e-1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{l^2} dl = \dfrac{1}{2(e-1)} $$

Comment: Nielsen and Chuang errata: https://michaelnielsen.org/qcqi/errata/errata/errata.html You can check here.

Comment: please use mathjax to write down the equation in the post

Comment: @MartinVesely It's not in there, is it? (It's page 224 in my old copy)

Comment: @M.Stern: I see. Just to inform you, it is also wrong in my 10th aniversary edition (2016).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a typo as mentioned in the comments by [M Stern](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14898/in-nielsen-and-chuang-how-can-frac12e-1-result-from-frac12-int-e-1#comment20510_14898)

[image]